# Сервер-посредник не отдает контент

Tags: php

Имеется 2 сервера. Один главный, другой посредник.
Задача такова:
Главный сервер хочет получить контент с другого сайта через сервер-посредник, т.е проксированием.

Главный сервер отправляет GET запрос:

```
file_get_contents('http://сервер_посредник?url=http://someurl')
```

Сервер-посредник открывает требуемую ссылку и отправляет контент:

```
echo file_get_contents($_GET['url'])
```

Дело в том, что при обращении к серверу-посреднику через браузер, требуемый контент из http://someurl выводится. А при обращении через главный сервер идет долгое ожидание, а после просто time out. Я пробовал поставить на сервере-посреднике просто `echo 'test123'` чтобы убедиться ,что сервер-посредник доступен для главного сервера. В итоге главный сервер получает вывод из `echo`, а как только добавляю `file_get_contents`, долгое ожидание.

Comment: Так может нет сети между ними? Какой-нибудь `wget/curl` с этим же URL работает с сервера?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen это включено в php.ini?

Comment: wget качает, curl бесконечно грузит. `echo 'test123'` ведь получает, именно когда `file_get_contents` добавляю, не грузит ничего.

Comment: @AntonZikov включено

Comment: Попробуйте итоговый URL на главном сервере прогнать через urlencode()

Comment: @AntonZikov делал, не помогло.